# SDL Tridion 2009 SP1 Custom URL get current field value

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

I am connecting to a Custom URL on a component field which contans the following code

```
        function SaveAndClose()
        {
            var newValue = new Array();
            newValue[0] = "/feed.ashx?type="+ $("#Type").val() + "&user="+ $("#User").val();
            window.returnValue = newValue;
            self.close();
        }
       document.write("Current Value:");
       document.write(window.dialogArguments.fieldValue);
```

The SaveAndClose Function works perfect and sends the value back to the component, but window.dialogArguments.fieldValue always returns undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the `customArguments` property on the dialogArguments:

```
document.write(window.dialogArguments.customArguments.fieldValue);
```

Comment: Please add a comment to the documentation saying this so that the technical writers can fix it.

Comment: Sorry to hear that - hope you didn't waste too much time on it! 
I'd ask you to comment on the page that had the incorrect example, but this was before the documentation was online...